# Nesting LongListSelector inside LongListSelector - performance problems and other problems

Tags: silverlight-toolkit, windows-phone-7

The application contains LongListSelector which shows master items (100-300 elements). When clicked on an item, then it expands and shows details items (100 elements) - which are placed inside nested LongListSelector.

(LongListSelector from Silverlight Toolkit for Windows Phone - August release.)

The problems are:

1. Performance - expanding details list takes a few seconds which is
   not acceptable - probably it generates UI controls for all items
   which is obviously very bad idea
2. Unable to scroll details items (scrolling master items works OK)
3. Not working ElementBinding to LayoutRoot.DataContext from LongListSelector.ItemsTemplate

When switching to plain old ItemsControl points 2,3 are solved but still performance problem exist.

Can anybody suggest me any solution or suggestion how these problems can be solved? Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like this is the way of pain. Can the details not be on a separate page or popup?

Comment: This is customer requirement. From logical point of view - if there are only 5-10 detail items visible at the moment then it shouldn't be a problem to materialize only visible items instead of all items.

Comment: This is one of those situations where it's best to explain it to the client. That is, he can _probably_ have it the way he wants it but it will take a few days to find out, _or_ he can have equivalent functionality today. I think I know what they will choose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having nested scrollable controls is only going to cause problems with them fighting for the input events. It's not a supported scenario in the Metro UI so you'll get no help trying to make it work.

Change the inner `LongListSelector` to an `ItemsControl`. That should get you closer to the experience you're after.

Comment: I started with nested ItemsControl but the performance was poor, so the idea was to find better solution.

Comment: I placed expanderview inside longlistselector and it is somehow promising, but there are plenty of weird errors so I'm giving up :(